# UIFont.LineHeight removed in MonoTouch 4.0. Alternatives?

Tags: xamarin.ios

The property for UIFont.LineHeight was removed in MonoTouch 4.0. What was the motivation behind this and are there any alternatives or do I have to write my own binding to get that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an oversight, my apologies for that.  It will be reintroduced in 4.0.1.  In the meantime you can do:

```
Messaging.float_objc_msgSend (font.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("lineHeight"));
```